# How to play wmv file in UIWebview of ios

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

How to play wmv file in UIWebview  of ios?. If is there any other options let me know?.

Answer (score 0):

Please read document [Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/MediaLayer/MediaLayer.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007898-CH9-SW4).

Video Technologies that supported are **mov**, **m4v**, **mp4**, **3gp**

> So .wmv file can't be played.

If you're so much interested in this take a look at [source code](https://github.com/coderyi/Eleven)

iTunes link for the same [Elevan player](https://itunes.apple.com/cn/app/elevenplayer/id1033773648)

Comment: Thanks for reply. Is there any other option available except converting to mp4 format

Comment: @Rakesh Its implemeted in the source code i have given. please follow that. Thank you

Comment: @Saranjith can i get the video url which actually play in WKWebView see this and please some kind of help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55377677/how-to-detect-avplayer-and-get-url-of-current-video-from-wkwebview

Comment: i see but if you can help me with my question(above comment)

Answer (score 0):

**wmv file can't be played.**

But you can convert wmv to mp4 in background and then play it.

Below is the code for conversion.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyVideo.mp4"];
NSURL *outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

[self convertVideoToLowQuailtyWithInputURL:localUrl outputURL:outputURL handler:^(AVAssetExportSession *exportSession)
{
    if (exportSession.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted) {
        // Video conversation completed
    }          
}];

- (void)convertVideoToLowQuailtyWithInputURL:(NSURL*)inputURL outputURL:(NSURL*)outputURL handler:(void (^)(AVAssetExportSession*))handler {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:outputURL error:nil];
    AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:inputURL options:nil];
    AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough];
    exportSession.outputURL = outputURL;
    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4;
    [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^(void) {
         handler(exportSession);
     }];
}
```

Comment: I have used this functionlaity but this Error type I get "Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x60000268e490 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-16979 "(null)"}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-16979), NSURL=file:/Users/pabitr/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8E870560-DF6A-46AA-93D9-8CD8C34CB277/data/Containers/Data/Application/DC2DE15A-0EDB-4A21-9824-8C03D5BD01FE/Documents/MyVideo.mp4 -- file:///, NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed}"